# How to send mail from 10 minute disposable email via SMTP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, gmail, smtplib

This is my code for the gmail smtp server.

```
def verify_email(self, user_email, sending_email, password):
    port = 465
    self.sending_mail = sending_email
    self.password = password
    if (re.fullmatch(regex, user_email)):
        self.user_email = user_email
    else:
        raise Exception("Sorry, your email is invalid.")
    self.email_msg = f"""
        Subject: Verify Email

        Is this you, {self.username}?

        Please enter the code below to verify:
        [{verify_code}]

        From,
        {self.sending_mail}
        """
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
            server.login(self.sending_mail, self.password)
            server.sendmail(self.sending_mail, self.user_email, self.email_msg)

    except:
        print("An error has happened. Please check the spelling of your email, "
              "or try again. ")
```

How can I use the [10 minute mail](https://10minutemail.com/) SMTP server?

I used Google but I didn't understand any of it.
When I used Gmail I got this error:

```
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g15-20020a056a0023cf00b004e17e11cb17sm9404507pfc.111 - gsmtp')
```

So I decided to use 10minute mail. In my gmail account, I can't change the settings to allow Less Secure Apps.

Comment: It seems to me that this message could not be more clear: `Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail`. Did you follow the advice? Realistically,  if Google rejects the credentials you present, then submitting the same credentials using different software is unlikely to get you very much further.

Comment: But in my account, I cant change that setting.

Comment: As an aside, your message is not a valid RFC5322 message. The least intrusive fix is to remove the leading spaces; but really, don't try to piece together an email message from strings if you don't know exactly what you are doing - use the Python `email` library (and specifically the modern `EmailMessage` API, not the obsolescent `email.message.Message` / `MIMEText` et al. stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail recently announced that they wouldn't allow unsecure connections like SMTP on May 30th of 2022.

Using SMTP through gmail requires that you enable the setting "Allow less secure apps" in account settings to be able to connect.

I'd try something like Yahoo, or Outlook, or another email provider that allows SMTP. Look up their server information, and what security privilege's you need to enable for the connection to happen for which provider you choose.

I'm not familiar with 10 Minute Mail, but just wanted to give that insight to Gmail's SMTP server. Hopefully someone else can help you set it up through 10 minute mail.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not allow to send emails like this anymore, to protect users from sharing their own password. Which is a good thing and there is a better way now!

You first have to activate Two-Factor Authentication and then after having activated 2FA you can create app passwords that give an app full access to your Google account with this new passcode (so without having to share your real password).

You can create on here:
https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification

At the end of the page, you'll find "App Passwords".

You also have the option to manage and edit or delete or update the passwords there so no harm for your account can be done anymore.
You should still be careful though, as you give a third party access to your Google account.